# cannot access javascript global variables

Tags: javascript, scope, global

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Group Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascript/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var global = new Array();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/json",
        success: function(reports){
            global = reports;
            process(reports);
            return global;
            }
        });


function process(reports){
    for (i=0; i<reports.length; i++) {
        document.write(i + " : "+reports[i].fields.report_name+"<br>");
        }
    }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

OK, so there is my code. I am trying to use the JSON data throughout my code, but for some reason, I get a "reports is undefined" error whenever I try to use the reports object outside of the $.ajax() function.

According to JSLint, the code looks good, AND
lists both the reports and the variable global as global variables.

If I try to run anything that uses either of those outside, it won't work.

```
'success'(reports)
global
global
line 22
process(reports)
global
document
```

Comment: Oh yeah, screw the existing global properties. Let's just pollute the global namespace with our own variables. We don't need some stupid IIFE wrapper. `:P`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access `reports` as global object only `global` can be accessed from every place.  `reports` is a local variable to success as well as for `process` function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var global = new Array();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/json",
        success: function(reports){
            global = reports;
            process(reports);
            return global;
            }
        });


function process(reports){
    for (i=0; i<reports.length; i++) {
        document.write(i + " : "+reports[i].fields.report_name+"<br>");
        }
    }
        // reports is undefined here. but global can be accessed (will be empty array before success function get called)
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind `$.ajax` is async, so unless you call your functions inside the success callback, the value might not be set yet.

Also you'd need to use `global` not `reports`.

Comment: I'm also curious if i chose to return "reports" would it then become available?